# Where to have PCB with microcontoller designed?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I’m involved in CNC milling/manufacturing/prototyping, a product we are designing needs an electrical interface that controls timing and dwell on 2 solenoids. This is something well outside of our skills and knowledge to accomplish on our own.

We’ve been looking into the world of electrical engineering for options to have a circuit board designed, with no luck. It seems all the places we are finding are prototyping services for PCB, but need existing circuit designs to complete the work.

What type of firm or engineer should we be seeking that can design the circuitry and programming? 
(Sample design parameters below)

- Control solenoids in a paintball gun, where the board will have a microswitch to register a trigger pull.
- End user adjustable solenoid dwell time, fire control selection (semi/auto/ect)
- LCD/OLED display to view setting parameters like: rate of fire, dwell, fire mode

Any help that points us in the right direction would be appreciated.

Edit: Following up from the answers below and contacting several engineering firms unable to design microcontroller circuitry/programming, they referred us towards the correct industry.

What we should’ve been looking for was, Application Specific Integrated Circuit (ASIC) design and solutions. Once we used the correct term “ASIC” thousands of providers now show up in our searches.

Comment: It would help to fill in your profile so those that might be interested could contact you.

Comment: I have no idea what is in the curriculum of a computer engineer, but I know mine electrical engineering one was riddled with programming. So this sounds like it is right up the electrical engineering alley.

Regarding companies or freelancers I think there are many options, since all you need is the manufacturing files it does not really matter where the company is located. Just make sure to ask for portfolio's of previous jobs etcetera.

Comment: Look toward the companies that send you similar things for manufacture, and find out who they use.

Comment: There is this site called Google, search for "freelance pcb design"

Comment: @Misunderstood Though it sounds like a lot more than PCB design is required. The guys I use do PCB layout but they are not necessarily up to determining requirements and engineering a hardware/firmware solution to a problem. They work from a finished schematic, BOM and dimensioned mechanical drawings.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany the guys that do PCB layout know lots of guys that do circuit design if they do not have guys in house.  They also know which guys are good and which suck.  The search term I used will find freelance sites like freelancer.com.

Comment: Yes that was the issue we had with the companies who prototype PCB boards. They want us to provide diagrams of the electrical circuits.

Comment: Freelancer.com is very interesting they have a whole section full of electrical engineers seeking side jobs/contracts.

Comment: @AlexT I doubt you want an ASIC for this. Unless your volume is huge, it's going to be a much more expensive solution than a microcontroller-based design.

Answer (score 2):

You want to outsource design and manufacturing.  Then you are looking for an engineering firm that provides solutions or consulting.
They will do the entire design and validation for you, often also production.  The ownership of the intellectual property is negotiable, this is a big factor in the price.

There are many of these companies around, they are often small. But some are big.
Some single market companies can also do this as a side project, they'll have the skilled people already.

You can also choose to hire someone temporarily via an engineering consultancy firm. *(I don't know the English term for this)*

Network on your linked-in, a few people from your uni years probably landed at one of those companies.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably consider the entire life cycle of this project, even if you are just going to be involved with prototyping. From determining the specifications, to deciding the UI to pre-production and manufacturing (especially including testing) and maintenance.

Frankly this sounds like quite a simple project, but still probably you'd want to prototype the functionality in something that does not necessarily look like the final product before committing to a PCB. There are certainly potential pitfalls that could lead to severe headaches and returns, and it's almost guaranteed if the designer is getting their experience on your design. Also, if high volume is possible you should pick a vendor with experience in design for (probably Asian) manufacturing. This could be done as a later step but it's always better done as early in the design process as possible.

Whether you deal remotely or not is a trade-off between finding the skills required and being able to communicate the requirements and suggestions back and forth efficiently, close cooperation is more useful in the early stages. For example, I am now dealing with a CNC vendor on another continent, with a language barrier etc, because they are one of the few in the world that has the very expensive equipment and skilled people to meet the xx nanometer tolerances required. If a few microns was okay, I would go down the street.